# OpenCV resizing captured IPLImage?

Tags: java, swing, opencv

I'm trying to capture image with OpenCV and make it a stream and display in an user-interface. I've been using the following code to display the image:

```
OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber;
JLabel webCamScreen__ = null;

grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber("VIDEO IP-ADDRESS");
grabber.setImageHeight(webCamScreen__.getHeight());
grabber.setImageWidth(webCamScreen__.getWidth());

grabber.start();

while (true) {
    IplImage grabbedImage = grabber.grab();    
    this.webCamScreen__.setIcon(new ImageIcon(grabbedImage.getBufferedImage()));

}

grabber.stop();
```

Captured image is displayed in JLabel-component and I'd like to resize the received image to fit inside the component. Image aspect ratio should be kept the same. Right now the received image overrides grapper's imageHeigth and imageWidth.

Comment: *"I'd like to resize the received image to fit inside the component"* So.. go for it. Or do you expect us to spoon feed the code to you? That's not how SO works. Make an attempt, and get back to us when you have a **specific** question.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
IplImage origImg = grabber.grab();
resizedImage = IplImage.create(webCamScreen__.getWidth(), webCamScreen__.getHeight(),
                        origImg.depth(), origImg.nChannels());
opencv_imgproc.cvResize(origImg, resizedImage);
this.webCamScreen__.setIcon(new ImageIcon(resizedImage.getBufferedImage()));
```

opencv_imgproc had a resize function by which I was able to resize the IPL-image.

Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless do you have a specific retrocompatibility issue, avoid using IPLImage which are deprecated from a long time.

Use [Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/core/Mat.html) instead.

Comment: I have, so using something else but IPLImage is not possible. I tried using Mat but couldn't get it work.